# Spring H2 database - cannot initilize and persist data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to create an app that fills a **`H2`** database with some data on the first startup and persists it. Unless I remove the db file, the data is saved in the file and not overwritten. If I remove the db file, I would like the app to create it again with the basic set of data. I've made two files `schema.sql` and `data.sql`.

**Schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ACCOUNT
(
    id      INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME    VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    BALANCE INT                NOT NULL
);
```

**Data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(NAME, BALANCE)
VALUES ('Wallet', 100);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(NAME, BALANCE)
VALUES ('Savings', 5000);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(NAME, BALANCE)
VALUES ('Budget3', 0);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(NAME, BALANCE)
VALUES ('Budget4', 0);
```

And my application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:./data/sample;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
```

In the current setup, the data.sql does not populate the db on first start. If I add `#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` - it populates the db on the first run, but causes issues afterwards.

Comment: I believe it's better if you use Liquibase or Flyway for that purposed, it will give you a lot more control over what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @MarcosBarbero, are there any good resources for Liquibase or Flyway you can recommend?

Comment: You can refer to Liquibase's official guide here https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `schema.sql` and `data.sql` you have to disable the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` ie. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) on how to initialize the database.

Answer (score 0):

i just tried with import.sql instead of data.sql and works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).